# NameError global variable undefined, even though it is in the same function, and wasn't imported?

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, global-variables, nameerror

this is my first question on this forum!
I am trying to write a test file for a class in another file (All in Python btw) and I get a NameError: global variable *name here* undefined. I'll show you some example code of what Im doing.

```
import unittest
from File import *


class TestFile(unittest.TestCase):

    def object_test_setup(self, elements): 
        s = CustomClass() #from imported File, have to import items this way.
        for item in elements:
            a.insert(item)
        return (a)

    def test_contains_tuple_element(self):
        '''Return True iff CustomClass contains tuple element'''
        custom_object = object_test_setup([1, "string!", ("TUP", "LE")])
        element = ("TUP", "LE")
        self.assertTrue(custom_object.__contains__(element)) # __contains__ is defined in File
```

yeah so the object gets initialized just fine, all the methods in the imported file work on the object, but for some reason my NameError says `NameError: global name 'object_test_setup' is not defined`

which I dont understand because everything is imported works in that file, I believe I imported correctly and the global NameError is from a function within the class itself. why wont this work? All help is much appreciated!

Many thanks,
Thomas

Comment: `self.object_test_setup(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a class method, so you need to call it like one:

```
custom_object = self.object_test_setup([1, "string!", ("TUP", "LE")])
```